# large text editing, paste replace

Tags: python, text, editing

I have a large text file with over ~200 million lines. It is split into blocks of approximately 50000 lines. What I need to do is replace lines 10-100 from all the blocks with lines 10-100 from the first block. Any ideas how to go about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use a `list`. First read the lines you want to use from the first block into a list. Next, read each other file in turn line by line, and write them out to a new file, but if the line number is between 1-100 then use the line from your list. Example that achieves your goal:

```
fnames = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"]

sub_list_start = 9
sub_list_end = 100

file1_line_10_to_100 = []

with open(fnames[0]) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        if i >= sub_list_start and i < sub_list_end:
            file1_line_10_to_100.append(line)
        if i >= sub_list_end:
            break

for fname in fnames[1:]:
    with open(fname) as f:
        with open(fname + '.new', 'w') as f_out:
            for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
                if i >= sub_list_start and i < sub_list_end:
                    f_out.write(file1_line_10_to_100[i - sub_list_start])
                else:
                    f_out.write(line)
```